# How many possible fruit could fit in a box?

Tags: probability, packing-problem

I'm bad at math and English so please forgive me.
I have infinite fruits like apple, orange, and mango and I want to fit  fruits in a  box that has a volume of 100 units. If an apple has a volume around 6 - 9 units, orange has a volume of 5-7 units, and mango has 7 - 10 units, then how many possibilities are there of fruits that fit the box? (How many apples, mangoes, and oranges can a box fit, and the box can have just one type of fruit.)

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing the shape of the box and the fruit, and then it would be very difficult.  Kepler conjectured the answer for oranges (spheres) in 1611, and the problem was finally disposed of in 2014.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing#Dense_packing.  For actual fruit, not mathematical abstractions, I doubt there's a mathematical solution.

Comment: Since only one type of fruit is to be chosen, it should be oranges as they have the least volume. The trouble is that if you squeeze hard enough, it will turn into orange juice.

Comment: its not have to be fruit, what i asked is if a container can fill with three object that dont have fixed size then how many possibility list of object that can fit. example, I can fit box with 20 orange that have size 5. or 10 orange size 6, 1  orange size 5, 4 apple size 6, 1 apple size 8